# Skype missing GPG key

Tags: gpg, skype

I wanted to install Skype on Scientific Linux 6.1:

```
yum install alsa-lib.i686 dbus-libs.i686 e2fsprogs-libs.i686 expat.i686 fontconfig.i686 freetype.i686 glib2.i686 glibc.i686 keyutils-libs.i686 krb5-libs.i686 libcap.i686 libgcc.i686 libICE.i686 libpng.i686 libselinux.i686 libSM.i686 libstdc++.i686 libX11.i686 libXau.i686 libxcb.i686 libXcursor.i686 libXdmcp.i686 libXext.i686 libXfixes.i686 libXi.i686 libXinerama.i686 libXrandr.i686 libXrender.i686 libXScrnSaver.i686 libXv.i686 openssl.i686 qt.i686 qt-x11.i686 zlib.i686

vi /etc/yum.repos.d/skype.repo
[skype]
name=Skype Repository
baseurl=http://download.skype.com/linux/repos/fedora/updates/i586/
enabled=1
gpgkey=http://www.skype.com/products/skype/linux/rpm-public-key.asc
gpgcheck=1

wget http://www.skype.com/products/skype/linux/rpm-public-key.asc
rpm --import rpm-public-key.asc
yum install skype
```

But the [Skype RPM public key link](http://www.skype.com/products/skype/linux/rpm-public-key.asc)
returns an `HTTP/404` (not found) error.

Where is the GPG key for Skype?

#### Update:

So there is no GPG check when downloading Skype? OMG! Please say it's not true..

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://scientificlinuxforum.org/index.php?showtopic=569) how to install Skype on Scientific 6. Basically, you shouldn't do the check by yourself.

I will outline the steps here:

1. `# yum install alsa-lib.i686 dbus-libs.i686 e2fsprogs-libs.i686 expat.i686 fontconfig.i686 freetype.i686 glib2.i686 glibc.i686 keyutils-libs.i686 krb5-libs.i686 libcap.i686 libgcc.i686 libICE.i686 libpng.i686 libselinux.i686 libSM.i686 libstdc++.i686 libX11.i686 libXau.i686 libxcb.i686 libXcursor.i686 libXdmcp.i686 libXext.i686 libXfixes.i686 libXi.i686 libXinerama.i686 libXrandr.i686 libXrender.i686 libXScrnSaver.i686 libXv.i686 openssl.i686 qt.i686 qt-x11.i686 zlib.i686`
2. `# gedit /etc/yum.repos.d/skype.repo`
3. In the file above you basically post the following:

   ```
   [skype]
   name=Skype Repository
   baseurl=http://download.skype.com/linux/repos/fedora/updates/i586/
   enabled=1
   gpgkey=http://www.skype.com/products/skype/linux/rpm-public-key.asc
   gpgcheck=0
   ```
4. `# yum install skype`
5. `# chmod a+x /usr/bin/skype`

If you have problems with Video Chat do the following:

```
# mv /usr/bin/skype /usr/bin/skype.proper
# cat << EOF > /usr/bin/skype
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
skype.proper
EOF
```

The old Skype executable has been renamed `skype.proper`.

UPDATE:

i have done some Google research about the GPG key for skype, but no one seems to have it, as you can see [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-175692.html) and here (at the skype forums), and [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/need-gpg-key-for-skype-for-importing-and-installation-608464/) too, and [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=skype%20GPG%20key&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) is the Google page with the search i have done and it full with complains about the missing key.

I would recommend, to install Skype with either the instructions above, or to download it directly from the skype website [here](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/).

Comment: http://www.skype.com/products/skype/linux/rpm-public-key.asc -->> error 404...

Comment: so there are no GPG checks when using Skype? this is madness!

Comment: madness? this. is. MICROSOFT

Comment: this installation instructions are actually from the Scientific Linux forums, at the start of the answer there is the link although you should wait a little for it to load since it is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the key they used to sign RPMs with, I copied it below. I got it from [this Fedora forums posting](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=175692) and also using wayback on http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/infosys/phone/skype/rpm-public-key.asc which I saw mentioned a few places.

The key by itself is worthless if the skype isn't actually signing their RPMs which is indeed the case. The gpg check is complaining because the RPM isn't signed, not because you don't have the key.

If you run `rpm -K some.rpm` you can check to see if an RPM is signed. Notice in the output in the command below, the skype RPM does does not list 'gpg' anywhere whereas the signed 'at' RPM from CentOS does and the signed 'aspell' from Scientific Linux does. You can run `rpm -Kv some.rpm` if you want more verbose output. The RPM website has [more info on signing RPMs](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-checksig-using-rpm-k.html#S2-RPM-CHECKSIG-WHEN-NOT-SIGNED) and how to tell if they're signed if you're interested.

```
$ rpm -K skype-2.1.0.81-fc.i586.rpm
skype-2.1.0.81-fc.i586.rpm: sha1 md5 OK
$

# This is a CentOS RPM that I have already imported the key for.
$ rpm -K at-3.1.10-43.el6.i686.rpm
at-3.1.10-43.el6.i686.rpm: rsa sha1 (md5) pgp md5 OK
$

# This is a Scientific Linux RPM that I do not have a key for.
# It complains I don't have it but still shows the RPM as being signed.
$ rpm -K aspell-0.60.6-12.el6.i686.rpm 
aspell-0.60.6-12.el6.i686.rpm: (SHA1) DSA sha1 md5 (GPG) NOT OK (MISSING KEYS: GPG#192a7d7d) 
$
```

In summary, the problem you have isn't that you can't get their GPG key, it's that they don't sign their RPMs. You're going to have to go without the gpgcheck to get skype installed.

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.2.4 (GNU/Linux)
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=Up0v
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to get the key securely via HTTPS rather than HTTP, currently from:

https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY

To get to the fingerprint, you can use:

```
gpg --import SKYPE-GPG-KEY
gpg --fingerprint Skype
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this method.

- Import or Download GPG Key from [here](http://pgp.mit.edu:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xD66B746E) .
- Download the GPG key and then export it to the expected place as `root`

  `gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0xD66B746E;
  gpg -a -o /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-skype --export 0xD66B746E;
  rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-skype;`
- Add or Update the following repo file int the `/etc/yum.repos.d/skype.repo`

---

```
[skype]     
name=Skype Repository     
baseurl=http://download.skype.com/linux/repos/fedora/updates/i586/     
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-skype 
enabled=1    
gpgcheck=1
```

---

- Download & Install Skype

  `wget http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-beta-fc10`

  - Install the other libraries that might be needed for skype to work

    `sudo yum install also-lib also-plugins-pulseaudio  dbus-libs e2fsprogs-libs expat fontconfig freetype glib2 glibc keyutils krb5-libs libpcap libgcc libICE libpng libselinux libSM libstdc++ libX11 libXau libxcb libXcursor libXdmcp libXert libXfixes libXi libXinerma libXrandr libXrender libXScrnSaver libXv openssl qt qt-X11 zlib`

    `sudo yum localinstall skype-*.rpm`

    - If it does not work still, then try `sudo yum localinstall skype-*.rpm --nogpgcheck`
- It seems the installed version needs some ld_preload hack to get executed. Update this in your ~/.bashrc.

  `alias skype='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype'`

However, if yum still returns package not signed, I would rather check the package is in its integrity with `-K` option. If I am sure that I have downloaded the rpm package from the right source and the correct website then I would go ahead and install away the package by passing the gpg check with `yum install --nogpgcheck skype` or disable the gpgcheck in the repo configuration file and proceed with installation.